# Android how to use GPS lastknownlocation IFF locationchangedlistener won't run

Tags: android, multithreading, gps, listener, coordinates

I have a service that runs this thread to get GPS coordinates

```
   LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   GpsListener gpsLocationListener = new GpsListener();
   long minTime = 5000; // 5 sec for test purposes...
   float minDistance = 1;
   lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime,
            minDistance, gpsLocationListener);
```

and of course my `gpsLocationListener` looks like this:

```
   class GpsListener implements LocationListener{

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              latitude = location.getLatitude();
              longitude = location.getLongitude();
              //float speed = location.getSpeed();
              checkin();

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

}
```

where the `onLocationChanged` method sends the latitude and longitude to a server once it is obtained.

Unfortunately this method doesn't run as reliably as I'd like in my testing, where I basically get up and walk around to see if it registers my location has changed.

How do I make a different function run if it hasn't updated in X amount of seconds. This different function will simply send the last known coordinates?

Insight appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set up a recurring timer. [Android - Reliably getting the current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120256/android-reliably-getting-the-current-location) might help you in what you are trying to do.