# class returns an OLD location

Tags: android, gps, android-location

The class often returns an OLD location. I usually need to run() a couple of times before the correct location is returned. Any thoughts?

Source code:

http://pastebin.com/JacG3JqJ

Answer (score 0):

check this question 
[Android - Reliably getting the current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120256/android-reliably-getting-the-current-location)

and note

```
   Location location=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```